# laravel route callback return controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes

hello i'm new to laravel and maybe this is silly for you guys out here.
in laravel 8 routing web.php i've created a route like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::post('/auth', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@auth');

Route::get('/home', function () {
    if (session()->has('username')) return view('home');
    else return redirect('/');
});

Route::post('/editprofile', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@edit_profile');
```

what i want to ask is, can we return the controller from callback like view as well? let's say i want to check the session when user edit his profile. so in route /editprofile, the second parameter isn't 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@edit_profile', but a callback function like route '/home'. like this:

```
Route::post('/home', function () {
    if (session()->has('username')) return controller('App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@edit_profile');
    else return redirect('/');
});
```

but it returns error haha. let's say i don't want to use the __construct method to check session. is it possible? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First things first,

Since you are returning from an if statement, no else is required

This

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    if (session()->has('username')) return view('home');
    else return redirect('/');
});
```

Should look like this;

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    if (session()->has('username')) {
        return view('home');
    }

    return redirect('/');
});
```

Second, dont worry about all that if else inside of the route and just pass it to your controller, throw a route middleware on it. Below is the basic auth middleware but you can also create your own

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');
```

You can read up more on middlewares here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware

Comment: thanks for the improvement in if statement. so basically there is no callback for controller returns using simple if? we have to use middleware?

Comment: You could do a `return Redirect::action('HomeController@index');` but you should keep all of this type of logic inside middlewares. it will keep the project tidy and get you used to using them. Not to mention closures inside routes prevent them from being cached.